# Htaccess file reset automatically how to fix this issue

Tags: htaccess

Often my WordPress htaccess file was reset am not able to find the root cause of this issue. But I guess this may happen when installing any plugin or manually take a complete backup of the site. Also, I have checked htaccess file permission as well.
Please let me know how to fix this issue soon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WordPress will reset the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment markers (unless you actively block this). However, you shouldn’t be manually editing the code in this block anyway.

Comment: When you say you've checked the permission, checked that it is what? If you don't want WordPress to change it you'll have to remove WordPress's permissions to write to it. Is that what you've done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Disabling Plugins:
   This may be due to some plugin. So not only disable plugin, also try deleting folder of the plugin and its files like installer.php (example file) in the uploads folder.
2. .htaccess File Permission
   Check for proper file permissions. More over you can check the debug log. If its a live website, just replace .htaccess with the new one.